# Calculating algorithmic complexity

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Given the following bit of code, how would I calculate the complexity?

```
for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {
    //some code
    //some code
    for (b = 0; b < j; b++) {
        //code
        for (c = 0; c < k; c++) {
            //code
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming the commented lines have complexity of 1, would the complexity be calculated as follows?

a loop happens $i$ times

b loop happens $i^2j$ times

c loop happens $i^3j^2k$ times

Complexity = $2i + i^2j + i^3j^2k$?

Comment: Why do you think the b loop happens $i^2j$ times?  Each invocation of the loop will run $j$ times, and it is invoked $i$ times (because that's how often the first loop runs).

Comment: @tabstop, I really haven't the foggiest. I guess it would run $ij$ times? I'm having difficulty grasping asymptotics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the inner `c` loop. Suppose you add a counter statement `ctr++;` to it. Because there loop count is  `k`, one complete `c` loop adds `k` to the counter and therefore **one** pass through the `b` loop adds `k` to the counter: there are `j` passes of the `b` loop and thus a total increment of `j*k`. Repeat the argument for the `i` passes of the `a` loop and you get an overall count of `i*j*k` for your whole code snippet.

Comment: Would it not then be $ijk + ij + 2i$? The inner c loop I understand now happens $ijk$ times, but the code inside the b loop (but outside the c loop) would happen $ij$ times, for example. I know that it would tend to $ijk$, but as an interstitial step, is the complexity $ijk + ij + 2i$?

Comment: Yes: Your count $ijk+ij+2i$ is correct if you replace every `//some code` and 
`// code` with `ctr++`. But for complexity considerations you are normally interested in the highest order from the inner loop.

Comment: Cheers, you've been a great help.